# Como obter tipo de usuário em view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, autenticação, asp.net-identity, owin

Tenho um projeto Asp.Net MVC que usa **Individual User Account** com **Owin**. Tudo está funcionando perfeitamente, mas eu gostaria de obter o tipo de usuário (`role`) na `View`.

Estou usando `Request.IsAuthenticated` para saber se o usuário está autentificado, então existe alguma forma de obter os `roles` do usuário?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara, acredito que algo assim resolva o seu problema.

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
        @if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
        {
            <li>
                @Html.ActionLink("Administrativo", "index", "Administrativo")
            </li>
            <li class="nav-divider"></li>
        }

}
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado mesmo @joaoeduardorf

Comment: Valeu, precisando de algo dá um toque.